# How to display label text with timestamp as "seconds:milliseconds" in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How can I have a timestamp as "ss:mm" where mm = milliseconds?

Please let me know.

Comment: Probably but what is the content like?

Comment: What format is the timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting milliseconds is actually pretty easy. I created a category a while back to do this for me - all you need is a `NSTimeInterval`.

```
- (NSNumber *)getMilliseconds 
{
    return [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
}
```

So if you want a timestamp with seconds and milliseconds, do this:

```
 NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"ss"];
 NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];

 NSString*mystamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%i",dateString,[self getMilliseconds]];

 NSLog(@"Timestamp with Milliseconds: %@", mystamp);
```

If course you will have to edit my category if you want a custom date to calculate milliseconds from.

Hope it helps!